# Походження слова краватка

Tags: етимологія

В україньскі мові - краватка, в російській - галстук.

В мережі знайшла:
Название «галстук» в русском языке произошло от нидерл. halsdoek и нем. h.Halstuch, что означает «шейный платок». Однако в европейских языках более распространен другой корень — от фр. cravate. Из французского это слово перекочевало во многие европейские языки (например, нем. Krawatte, исп. corbata, укр. краватка, рум. Cravată, тур. kravat, польск. krawat). Французское же слово, вероятно, происходит от «кроат» («хорват»).

Яка ж етимологія слова "краватка", яке його первинне значення?

Comment: Будь ласка, не забувайте, що пояснення іноземною мовою має досить обмежену корисність і 不是很理解的 для тих, хто не володіє іноземною мовою, якою написане пояснення. Його варто перекласти англійською або українською.

Answer (score 4):

В етимологічному словнику знаходимо:

> **[крава́тка](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=71)**, *крава́тковий;*
>
> польська krawat «краватка», застаріле krawatka, чеська kravata, застаріле kravát, словацька kravata, слц. krawata, македонська *крава́та*, схв. *крава́та*, слн. kraváta «*те саме*»;
>
> через польську мову запозичено з французької; французька cravate оформилося внаслідок народної вимови слова croate (＜італійська croato (німецька Kroáte)＜схв. hr̀vāt) «хорват» у значенні «кольорова хустка, яку носять на шиї (частина одягу хорватських [ландскнехтів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%82) у французької армії)» (згодом «краватка»)
>
> Акуленко 136; Коломієць Мовозн. 1975/6, 84; Sł. wyr. obcych 398; Brückner 265; Machek ESJČ 290; Kluge—Mitzka 402; Bloch—Wartburg 1 188; Dauzat 217.
>
> Див. **[хорва́т](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf#page=200)**.

Отже, це слово походить від французького *cravate*, у значенні «кольорова хустка, яку носять на шиї».

Comment: Зрозуміло, спробую зараз виправити. Тільки мабуть буде не дуже коректно ваші дослідження видавати за свої. Можливо краще мені видалити відповідь, і ви напишете цю?

Comment: Та ні, чому… Корисна інформація. Я потім напишу іншу відповідь про те, що версія cravate←croate←hr̀vāt є застарілою ([хорватські ландскнехти з'явилися у французькій армії щонайменше через 345 років після того, як у французькій мові з'явилося слово _cravate_, тому найімовірніше французьке _cravate_ походить не від викривленого _хорват_, а від арабського _ربقة_](//fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cravate#Étymologie)) — але застарілу теж треба висвітлити, во вона дуже поширена.

Answer (score 2):

Вважають [давнöзатверџену і поширену відомість](/a/4042/585) застарілим і хибним, оскільки існують запереченя до достовірностӥ звязку часу між словом і появи — 1667 — [хорвацьких ландскнехтів](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9giment_Royal-Cravates_cavalerie) — слово зʼявило ся — [~1322](https://books.google.tn/books?id=yBwVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=cravate+crow+parchemin+Metz&source=bl&ots=E0FwQ2VcIE&sig=60YT77gjthGiaE8tWcP6uqb4TmU&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cravate%20crow%20parchemin%20Metz&f=false) — шчонаьменше ранїше на ~345 років.

Таким чином [можна пояснити](https://ia902301.us.archive.org/23/items/bub_gb_NhhudmEk0HgC/bub_gb_NhhudmEk0HgC.pdf#page=161) <sup>fr ↓</sup> і, наприклад [Antoine-Paulin Pihan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine-Paulin_Pihan) <sup>fr</sup> пояснює, похоџеня цӧго слова від арабського: **ربقة** [*rabqat*], де корінь [rbq](//books.google.com.ua/books?id=t_9NkGsNtcYC&pg=PA393&dq=%22rabqat%22), «звязати шию», «робити петлю».

> CRAVATE, s. f. (A.)
>
> ربقة [*rabqat*] *lien passé autour du cou* (dʼun homme ou dʼun animal), dérivé de ربق [*rabaq*] *entourer dʼun lien.* — Il existe en arabe un mot irès-rapproché de celui-eu, et qui ne peut manquer de confirmer le sens de *cravate*; cʼest رقبة [*raqabat*], qui veut dire *cou*. Au moyen de la iransposition des deux premières radicales (ce qui produit *qarabat*), on obtient facilement le ternie français *cravate*, sur lequel les étymologistes ne donnet rien de satisfaisant. — Les Portugais écrivent *cravata* el *gravata*, les Espagnols *corbata* et *corbatin*, les Italiens *cravatta*, et les Angais *cravat*.